# Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'android-test' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

I am trying to implement [Android-DirectoryChooser](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser) in my app, but I am new to Android Studio and I have come to a problem that I am not sure how to resolve.

I have created a new folder inside my project called "libraries" and I have copied this library project inside this folder. I then added a dependency like this:

```
compile project('libraries:android-directorychooser')
```

I then synced gradle and I have gotten the following error:

> Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'android-test' not found.

This is probably the problematic line in the project library build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android-test'
```

I've searched for a plugin named "android-test" but I've only found a library and it seems to be deprecated. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know you for what this plugin is necessary? When not remove it and your robolectric dependencies.

Plugin comes from https://github.com/robolectric/gradle-android-test-plugin

Robolectric is for unit tests, when you like to use it.(which I would recommend) then just add something like that

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.+'
}
}
```

to your lib module build.gradle file and the plugin should be found

Comment: Did this but it doesn't work yet. Still the same error. Shouldn't I specify the path to plugin somewhere in build.gradle? And where should  put this pugin in the project?

Comment: No and nowhere. Here is an official example how to use android-test https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle Maybe just remove this plugin, it's not necessary for development.

Comment: Sorry, but i have the same isseu, and can't solve it. Could you halp me ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419416/why-error17-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-library-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Android-test is no longer a separate plugin. The standard 'android' plugin now includes testing features. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing for more information.

Comment: Sorry, but i have the same isseu, and can't solve it. Could you halp me ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419416/why-error17-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-library-not-found