# Why Error:(17, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found?

Tags: java, android, android-library

I created a test project and add the library.

In the process of implementing it in my project I needed to add a line in `build.gradle` at`module` in `dependencies`, just such a line

```
compile project (':library')
```

And then added to the `settings.gradle`

```
include ':library', ':app'
```

and `build.gradle` at`Project` changed its `classpath` on

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

and all was good!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Once it's working, I tried to implement this library in the main project and carried out the same steps as in the first case, but got an error that I do not know how to fix. What have I done wrong?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I have tryed find how to solve it in google and have tryed add some lines in my gradle like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

And have tryed change number of tools version on 1.5.0 , but without success... What i am doing wrong? Help me

Comment: Your module folder is `library` but Android Studio says the name is `Application`, try to make it synchron (rename/refresh gradle). Also post your root build.gradle and settings.gradle, maybe it will help to find the issue. _Maybe an example library project will help: https://github.com/nenick/espresso-macchiato_

Comment: I have the same problem. Found a solution yet?